# Python Requests to CSV

Tags: python, pandas, api, url, python-requests

I've been trying to get the extract a JSON requests API result into a csv but I'm struggeling,

so far the below code return the value in the terminal

```
import requests
import csv
import json
from pprint import pprint
import urllib
import pandas as pd

url = "https://esi.evetech.net/latest/markets/10000002/orders/?datasource=tranquility&order_type=all&page=1"

payload={}
headers = {}
r = {}

response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)

text = response.read()
json_data = json.loads(text)

pprint(json_data)
df = pd.read_json(r)
df.to_csv("output.csv")
```

however Pandas return me with an error in regards of the Dictionary class? ( apologize I'm not really familiar when it come to coding )

Last question would be, what would be the logic to continue the url request beyond page=1 in the url variable? (order_type=all&page=**1** ) I don't know how many page the system have

thanks

Comment: Can you post the error trace you are getting to the question

Answer (score 1):

The error is reproducible with the code above and looks like some encoding error with the`urlib` library. But I was able to load the data successfully using the python `requests` module

```
import requests
url = "https://esi.evetech.net/latest/markets/10000002/orders/datasource=tranquility&order_type=all&page=1"
response = requests.get(url)
data = response.text
df = pd.read_json(data)
df.to_csv("output.csv")
```

Comment: That worked as well thanks a lot Justa! I'm trying to figure out a way for the page=1 now

Answer (score 1):

You've done `r = {}` and then `df = pd.read_json(r)`, so why would that work?

You can do either one of the following:

```
# from your code, above
text = response.read()

# create DF from serialized JSON data (a string)
df = pd.read_json(text)
```

Or:

```
# from your code, above
text = response.read()
json_data = json.loads(text)

# create DF from loaded JSON data (in your case a list of dicts)
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(json_data)
```

---

And the line `import urllib` should be `import urllib.request`. Or just use the 'requests' package, which you've also imported already.

---

Part 2:

To get all the pages, keep incrementing the value of `page` until you get an error or an empty response. (It's bad form to ask multiple unrelated questions on SO.) See [this answer for guidance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17777982/1431750) on how.

Comment: Perfect, that worked out I've got confuse as I never used pandas before - any suggestion for the page=1 ?

Comment: Btw, if you're happy with the answer, **["accept"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/193893) it**.

Comment: Edited. Either try writing the code for that with the link provided, or post a new question.